# Using PhysX on a Radeon GPU?

Tags: drivers, amd-radeon, gpu, physx

Is it possible to get PhysX to run on a Radeon GPU? I've seen various posts on forums claiming someone has found a way, but I was unable to locate any actual guides or software downloads to do it. Note: I don't mean running a GeForce and Radeon GPU in the same machine, I mean having only a Radeon GPU and having it run PhysX.

Here is one link talking about running PhysX hardware accelerated on a Radeon GPU:
[http://www.ngohq.com/news/14254-physx-gpu-acceleration-on-radeon-update-3.html](https://web.archive.org/web/20090809231300/http://www.ngohq.com/news/14254-physx-gpu-acceleration-on-radeon-update-3.html)
But it's just talking about a private beta program. And that was nearly 2 years ago. You'd think there would be something released by now.

Comment: [This](http://physxinfo.com/wiki/Hybrid_PhysX) might help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've done a bit of googling. Apparently, it is possible to run PhysX in *software* on an ATI card, which should apparently be built in. However, for hardware accelerated PhysX, you will need an Nvidia card, and furthermore, as of the most recent drivers update, can't even have an ATI card in the same machine at the same time. It's possible this will continue to change, and it looks like there are some hacked drivers out there (I couldn't find any myself, but I didn't look too closely). But the short answer is "**no**".

Comment: Yeah, I want to run it in hardware, not software. I added a link to my question to one page that talked about said 'hacked' drivers, but I couldn't find any more detail about it.

Answer (score 3):

### Current state - CUDA

It is currently not possible, as PhysX drivers do now work through any universal interface, they talk to nVidia card directly in a way which is not compatible with other HW vendors (CUDA).

### Possible future development - OpenCL

I think it is quite likely some solution will be released which will be using open standard line OpenCL for PhysX communication with the graphics card, but there is none yet. Such possibility was [discussed about a year ago](http://www.bit-tech.net/news/hardware/2009/03/27/nvidia-considers-porting-physx-to-opencl/1).

*Note: PhysX is owned by nVidia.*